# Using "Validators.requiredTrue" in a angular template driven form

Tags: angular, validation, angular2-template

I need to validate that a user has checked a "TOS" checkbox before allowing their registration. I would like to use the [requiredTrue validator](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#requiredTrue) for doing it, but I can't find in the docs a way of using this validator in a template driven form. Is it possible? If so, could you provide an example?

Comment: I ended up creating my own validator. If anyone needs something similar to me here it goes https://gist.github.com/jeanpchr/5c182fe50554c3699aab4f1e0d9cf4f8

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do the same, but apparently Checkboxes are totally ignored. 
If I attach the custom validator to a text input, it works fine. If I attach it to a checkbox it just doesn't run. No error, no nothing, the code in my directive (constructor + validate method) is not executed. Any clue about this?

Answer (score 0):

When validating whether a checkbox has been selected with angular form validation, you can just add the "required" validator. This works for both template driven and reactive forms. For template driven forms your html for the checkbox would look something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="TOS" ngModel required>
```

Or if you are using angular material:

```
<mat-checkbox name="TOS" ngModel required></mat-checkbox>
```

Both of the above examples will set the form validity to INVALID until the user checks the checkbox.

Comment: `requiredTrue` validates that the value `=== true`. The usage of `requiredTrue` is the same as `required`.

Answer (score 0):

Like @braden-w said you can use `requiredTrue` like the `required` directive:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="TOS" ngModel requiredTrue>
```

I had a problem in Ionic, where the `requiredTrue` directive was not working on an `<ion-checkbox>` tag. It had the exact same functionality than `required`. Therefore I created my own `checkboxRequiredTrue` directive. It somehow works, if I call the `Validators.requiredTrue` inside this directive.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[checkboxRequiredTrue]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: CheckboxRequiredTrueDirective,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class CheckboxRequiredTrueDirective implements Validator {
  validate(control: FormControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    return Validators.requiredTrue(control);
  }
}
```